# Cannot make tab bar controller a child view controller, what are the next best options?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I wanted a list on a table view for food, the arts, and each item on the table view cell to link to a tab bar controller which links to a list of of all food places on one tab and a map of all food places on another tab. here are the images of the tab view controller:
[image: food list]
[image: map list]

I essentially wanted 4 or 5 tableviewcells to link to 4 or 5 tab controllers. Any other way I can make this work?

Comment: Why not? ;)

Do I understand correctly? The question is whether there is a better way? Or they do not know how to call up a different tab from a ViewCotroller?

Comment: I was wondering how to connect from a button on a different view controller to a tabbed bar controller and I saw I can do it with a modal segue, so thanks, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on my own. A modal segue can be used to link to a tab bar controller. If  you're linking it with interface builder, just link it from the button to one of the actual tabs.